# How to find Sentiment Score and Magnitude (polarity) in R without using Google API?

Tags: r, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to do sentiment analysis for my data. Data contains the consumer survey open-ended question answers in multiple columns. I want sentiment score and magnitude for each column in R. Currently I have tried using Google API, I have created the account given all required keys in gl_nlp() from "googleLanguageR" Package in R. But it throws an error on billing is not enables wherein I have checked in the Google Cloud account billing is enables.

So, how can I find sentiment score and magnitude (Polarity) in R without using Google API and with the same accuracy?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please if you think your question has been solved, check it as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a good approach](https://www.tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html) using `tidytext` package developed by Julia Silge and David Robinson. This package follows the tidy approach in `tidyverse` package. The linked book mentions the existence of:

> The three general-purpose lexicons are
>
> - AFINN from Finn Årup Nielsen,
> - bing from Bing Liu and collaborators,
> - and nrc from Saif Mohammad and Peter Turney.

As it is also mentioned the `get_sentiments()` function allows you "to get specific sentiment lexicons without the columns that are not used in that lexicon."

Hope this answered your question if not let me know!

Comment: Hi Tito, Thanks for the help and currently I am trying tidytext and tidyverse only. And also with the help of some basic text function from stringr and using a positive and negative word dictionary I am able to get sentiment score in R and will check with tidytext about polarity. And definitely reach out to you if I will have any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the dataset extracted from the google api, then just apply `syuzhet` package. Documentation on it can be found here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/syuzhet/vignettes/syuzhet-vignette.html

Simply write: `data.frame(get_sentiment(df[,col#]))` and that should give you numerical sentiment scores.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tito Sanz - the tidytext way is the best and most transparent.
The way it employs 'tidy methods' is a good habit to get in to.

You can also use the 'QDap' package - if you are using english language. It will do what you want with polarity, but its difficult to justify (my opinion)

I also used the Google API - its a dog to set up but if you are using large datasets - there are restrictions on passing more than 1 million 'characters' per 24 hour period. Also once you exceed the credit they charge you a lot.

PM me if you have more specific quastions on Sentiment analysis